# Using loops in Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Here is my code. I want to edit this and make each side of the star a different color. So five different sides of a star meaning five different colors.

Essentially each side of the star has a different color. I am able to use any five colors. And also preferably I want to use loops. How can I do this?

```
import turtle

def star(color, sides, length, angle, distance):
    galileo = turtle.Turtle()
    galileo.color(color)  # colorful!
    galileo.width(5)  # visible!
    galileo.speed(0)  # fast!
    galileo.penup()
    galileo.left(angle)  # away from center
    galileo.forward(distance)
    galileo.pendown()  # start drawing
    for side in range(sides):
        galileo.forward(length)
        galileo.left(720 / sides)
    galileo.hideturtle()  # just the star

for angle in [180, 135, 90, 45, 0]:
    star("red", 5, 50, angle, 100)

for angle in [180, 135, 90, 45, 0]:
    star("blue", 5, 30, angle, 60)
```

Comment: It is good that you have written some code already. But in relation to the new feature you want, could you explain to readers what specific problem you had when you tried it? The usual answer to "I want this feature" is "OK, write it then".

Comment: Hahaha this makes so much sense! Sorry my bad i am new to coding and this website. But well noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the color in the for loop in the `star()` function instead of passing it as a parameter, for example

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange']
for side, color in zip(range(sides), colors):
    galileo.color(color)
```

`zip()` takes two iterables and 'zips' them together, so `zip([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` becomes `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`